# The linux kernel integrates the KVM why we install it again?

Tags: linux, kvm

All we know the linux kernel integrates the KVM, but why in the tutorial install the KVM ?

Use the below orders to install KVM:

[image]

I don't know why we should install it, if the Linux kernel integrates it.

Comment: Please post text as text and not as a screenshot/picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages that are mentioned provide userspace tools and hardware emulation capabilities which in addition to the bare KVM kernel module are needed to bring up VMs.

So, yes the kernel ships the KVM drivers but to make use of those you need additional tools to make use of the KVM functionality.